# Visual Studio taking long time to build and load solution because of Nugget

Tags: visual-studio, sitecore, nuget, nuget-package, sitecore7

Visual studio is taking a longer time to open the solution ,to build  and I just have 6 projects.When I examined the fiddler I see below requests to nugget and notice that once this request is complete the visual studio becomes responsive.

[image]

Can any body suggest the below:

1. what are these requests for nugget?
2. Is VS becoming slow because of this as I am suspecting?
3. How to stop these requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These requests can be a result of your solution enabling automatically restoring NuGet packages, 
You can disable it in the VS under Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings, and 
unchecked the "Allow NuGet to download missing packages".

If you need package restore, make sure that you have a good connection to the NuGet Gallery or disable all the unrelevant sources, under the Package Manager Settings.

bye